# Uploading sketch to ATMEGA328 via FTDI with some pins set to HIGH logic

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, atmega, atmega328p

I recently changed my PCBA design so that the digital pins 4, 5, & 6, are set to HIGH logic by default (so I can use some switches on these inputs).

However, now when I upload a sketch to the board via an FTDI breakout, I get an error: `avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30`

Could having these pins set to HIGH affect the sketch upload? The chip bootloaded fine, and in a previous iteration of the board there weren't any problems uploading sketches.

I have done a loop-back test to a previous board to test whether the FTDI breakout board is working correctly, and it is working fine.

Here is my schematic:
[image]

Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: We have no clue what bootloader code you use, what pins it uses and what pins you pulled up. So anything is possible and the pull ups may affect the skecth upload. But we don't know. If you want an answer, post details.

Comment: Do you still have a 'known-good-unit' of the previous PCBA that you can use to check that your FTDI breakout still works? The avrdude 'not in sync' message usually indicates complete lack of communication, which could be due to a broken cable or due to lack of system power supply, etc. If you can test the FTDI on a known-working board that helps narrow down the cause.

Comment: do a loopback test on the FTDI module

Comment: I bootloaded using the Minicore library, running at 2MHz internal.
I haven't pulled up the pins in bootload. They are pulled up via external resistors.
I should be able to find a known good unit, so I'll do a loopback test using the FTDI module.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a new batch of boards, so you can't be sure if the pull-ups are actually the cause for the chips to fail. For example, if you are doing anything timing critical with the chip, such as using and UART, please understand that the internal oscillator should not be used for anything that is timing critical. Start removing pull-ups and determine if the internal oscillator is accurate enough.

Comment: I'll be doing a loop-back test to the last known-good-unit today. The issue is actually getting the software to upload to the chip. But, I assume the UART upload is the timing critical process you are referring to? I have two other boards I can also test, to see if it's just the chip on this board that's internal clock calibration is too low tolerance.

Comment: I have done a loop-back test on a previous board revision. The FTDI breakout board is working correctly.

Comment: Is the FTDI interface 3.3V or 5V?

Comment: The FTDI breakout is 5V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making another board with another ATMEGA328 on it, this board uploaded fine. No design changes were required. I believe the reason I couldn't upload over the FTDI breakout before was due to the particular ATMEGA328 having too low a tolerance on it's internal oscillator, although I could be wrong since I was boot loading it to run at 2MHz which I thought would be slow enough.

A work-around which works is to use an Intermediary Arduino Uno, set as 'Arduino as ISP'. This then allowed me to use the 'Upload using programmer' option, utilising the SCK, MISO, MOSI, Reset pins, which worked well. Although this process is a little more time consuming.

Comment: Thanks you all for the advice that helped me to find this solution.